# C++: compiler optimization or bad design?

Tags: c++

I am trying to optimize an application which searches in large "databases".

My first application used a brute-force approach, searching for all documents in database and compare them to my query:

```
for(i = 0; i < n_base; ++i)
{
    float dist = compute_distance(query, *base[i]);
    query_result[i] = std::make_pair(dist, i);
}
std::partial_sort(query_result.begin(),query_result.begin()+K, query_result.end(), compare_score_idx_sort);
query_result.resize(K);
```

Then I tried another approach using a codewords vocabulary and assigning each document in the database to its nearest codeword. This gives me a list for each codeword of database documents.

My database is then stored into this container:

```
std::vector< std::pair< unsigned int, std::vector< unsigned short > > **  base = new std::vector< std::pair< unsigned int, std::vector< unsigned short > > * [NK];
```

where `NK` is the vocabulary size.

Then when I search in the database with this type of structure I find the `N` nearest codewords of my query and loop over the lists:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < nearest_codewords.size(); ++i)
        {
            for(unsigned int j = 0; j < base[nearest_codewords[i]]->size(); ++j)
            {
                std::pair< unsigned int, std::vector< unsigned short > > base_item = (*base[nearest_codewords[i]])[j];
                float dist = compute_distance(query,base_item.second);
                query_result[base_item.first] = std::make_pair(dist, base_item.first);
            }
        }
std::partial_sort(query_result.begin(), query_result.begin()+K, query_result.end(), compare_score_idx_sort);
```

When I browse 25% of my database with this version I only have less than a 50% drop in execution time (110 ms -> 65 ms).

I am curious then, is it a compiler optimization which caches the data in the first example which makes it faster, or contiguous data access... Or is it simply a bad design for the second example, if yes, do you have hints on how to improve it?

PS: I compile with these options : `-O2 -msse2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mention the contiguous data access. There is a lot of data out there relating to how important this is becoming, especially with the speed and size of the caches we are no getting in the hardware.

Here is a link to an article mentioning a video by Bjarne at Going Native 2012; http://bulldozer00.com/2012/02/09/vectors-and-lists/

I think what you are seeing is the improvements because of the contiguous (or near contiguous) data layout in memory.

Edit: I found the other video I was looking for; http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-661 Herb Sutter goes into some detail about this with very nice graphs, diagrams, explanations etc. from around the 23:30 mark and he picks up Bjarne's material at around the 46:00 mark.